# PHP Retrieving data from a JSP search page

Tags: php, jsp

I have a php page that has a text field and a submit button.  The textfield is going to take in a liquor license number.  On submit, I want for the number to be searched via the New York State Liquor Authority website. The New York State Liquor Authority has a License number search page: 
http://www.trans.abc.state.ny.us/JSP/query/PublicQueryLicenseNumSearchPage.jsp

How could I search their site and retrieve the data for the search based on what the user inputs and submits on my apge? Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have their permission to do this?

Comment: You should probably look into cURL.

Comment: I didn't know that I would need their permission.  I guessed that it is a public site and a public search, so I would not need permission.  I will check that out and see if what I am trying to do is against their regulations.  I really just need a way to verify whether if certain users have a valid liquor license.

Comment: If you're doing it once or twice for personal use, that's one thing.  If you're making a public facing site that's leaching off their site, then yeah, you should not be doing that without their permission.

Comment: I just sent an email to the webmaster regarding the necessary permissions for data retrieval.  Now the questions still stands, would cURL be the only way to get info from their site? or is there a better way?

Comment: If they give permission, they might have an API. If not, then yes cUrl is they way forward. It is actually quite simple when you get used to it